# how to know that how many dynamic controls created?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, dynamic

I have created dynamic row on click of button in table using following code :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var counter = 1;
                function displayResult()
                {
                    counter++;
                    document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><select name="list_dispatch_state" id="list_dispatch_state"><option value="01">01</option><option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="txt_email'+ counter +'" id="txt_email'+ counter +'" value='+ counter +'></td>';            
                }
        </script>

    <body>
      <form action="Dogetdat" method="post"> 
        <table id="myTable" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <br />
            <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert new row</button> 
            <input type="submit">
      </form>    
   </body>
```

my question is that, on click of button new row and control inside it created but when I click on submit then form submitted to servlet page.
Then how servlet will know that how many data are received ?

Because in servlet I ll get data using

```
String str1= request.gerParameter("txt_email");
```

how servlet will know that how many variable it have to create and what will be the name of that ? what will I have to pass in `request.gerParameter("");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following `request.getParameterValues` and get the result as an array

```
String emails[] = request.getParameterValues("txt_email");
```

Comment: I think this one is good idea, and what about `<select>` control ? shall I have to do same for that or any change ?

Comment: @user3145373 yes you can use this approach for `select` element also.

Comment: and sir in servlet I have add this all data to database  so how would I know that which one data I ll have to add in table ? and Shall I have to use array for to get all data from jsp page ? in short how to add data inside the database and which one to add that how to know ?

Comment: @user3145373 for example if you need `email, phone` details need to be entered into the database. You can get both the arrays in the servlet using the `request.getParameterValues` api. Get the length of any array. Loop through a counter say `i`. Store `email[i],phone[i]` to the database. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that I know but I am getting problem in query formulation. i.e. which data are received and as per it will be entered into database. suppose i get value `BLUE` for `color` then how do i know that color value is passed ? I want to separate received data from jsp and as per it, they should be added in db. suppose my query is `insert into tbl(f1,f2,f3) value(v1,v2,v3);` then how would i know that in which column name `(i.e. f1,f2,f3)` i have to add value `i.e. v1,v2,v3` here

Comment: If suppose you have `email` array & `phone` array. And the column names are 'ContactEmail' and 'ContactPhone'. Then inside the iterator (if your client construction is proper `email.length==phone.length`) `insert into ContactData(ContactEmail,ContactPhone) value('"+email[i]+"',"+phone[i]+"'");`